# fix the error of File " line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'Account' is not defined

Tags: python

I run those code in Python online, but get the error message 'File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'Account' is not defined'; I wonder how I could define "Account" there? thanks a lot! This is my first Python code.

```
class SavingAccount(Account):
 def _init_(self, holder_name, saving_rateaccount_number=None):   
    super()._init_(holder_name, account_number) 
    self.saving_rate = saving_rate
def _repr_(self): 

return 'SavingAccount('+str(self.holder_name)+', '+str(self.saving_rate)+', '+str(self.account_number)+')'
saving_account=SavingAccount('saving_1', 0.02)
print(saving_account)
```

Comment: Do you have a class called Account? And is it above your child class "SavingAccount"

Comment: Actually this is from a homework of my class, the teacher asks "what does the code would print", so I tried the code online here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ and get the error.

Comment: By the way, I wonder how I could make it work, I mean how to define the parent class(?). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Exactly, so you cant copy that code and try and run it, you need another arent class called Account. You should look into inheritance and classes. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/inheritance

Answer (score 1):

If you define the class `Account` in another Python file, you have to have `from other_file import Account` before `class SavingAccount(Account):` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```py
class My_class ( Other_class ):
    def __init__(self,...):
        # code lines
    def my_method(self,...):
        # more code
```

It means that `My_class` object will inherit `Other_class` methods and atributes, so you will have to define `Other_class` before in order to use it in `My_class`. In conclusion the new class will have it's own methods and atributes and also `Other_class` methods and atributes.

Example:

```py
class Other_class():
    def __init__(self,...):
        # constructor code lines
    def other_method(self,...):
        # more code lines 

class My_class( Other_class ):
    def __init__(self,...):
        # other constructor code lines
    def my_method(self,...):
        # some more code lines
```

You can find the full information [in Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

PS: my recomendation is to always see the official documentation, you can even discover more thinks and expand you knowledge on the language. By the way you will see how useful is Python, keep it up